# Sorting data in Google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm collecting data with a Google Form, and storing it in a spreadsheet.

I would like to write a script to create separate spreadsheet, sorted by name.

E.g.

I have three users: `Daniel`, `Gilles` and `Jean Pierre`.

I want to create a separate sheet from the main one, listing only the data submitted.

So, if the name is `Daniel` in row 2, I want to copy all the data in the row to the second sheet

So far:

```
function tri() 
{
     var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
     var data = ss.getDataRange().getValues();
     var sheet2 = ss.getSheets()[1]; 

     for (var t=1; t<data.length; t++)
     {   
         if (data ='Daniel')
         {   
             sheet2.appendRow([data]);    
         }
     }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for code, you can do this in the spreadsheet. The solution I'd prefer would be to create named tabs for each of your users, put their name in cell A1 of their sheet, then use the spreadsheet `QUERY` function to populate their sheet. Something like this in cell A3, say:

```
=query('Form Responses'!A1:Z,"select * where B = '" &A1 & "'")
```

Adjust the source to match your reality (`'Form Responses'!A1:Z`).

---

But if you must use script, try this:

```
function tri() 
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses");
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var users = ['Daniel', 'Gilles', 'Jean Pierre'];

  for (var user=0; user<users.length; user++) {
    // Open sheet with user's name; create if needed
    var dest = ss.getSheetByName(users[user]);
    if (!dest) dest = ss.insertSheet(users[user], user+1);

    var newData = [];
    newData.push(data[0]); // copy headers
    for (var row=1; row < data.length; row++) {
      // If row is for this user, copy it
      if (data[row][1] === users[user]) newData.push(data[row]);
    }
    // Clear user's sheet, then save collected data
    dest.clearContents();
    dest.getRange(1, 1, newData.length, newData[0].length).setValues(newData);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As a complement to Mogsdad (excellent) answer I'd like to add a detail that might be important.

Since your users are filling a form you can't be sure about the way they will be entering their names, will Daniel write "*Daniel*" or "*DANIEL*" or even "*daniel*" if he is in a hurry ? and for "*Jean Pierre*" it could even be worse since normally there should be a hyphen between *Jean* and *Pierre* !!!

So I'd suggest to add some logic around the name detection or, other possible solution if you know exactly who will fill this form, use a list select in your form to choose the names from.
This latest solution would be the simplest one of course...

Otherwise you can simply use :

```
...data[row][1].toUpperCase().replace(/ /g,'') == users[user];// users should then be defined in UPPERCASE
```

for example to avoid any upper/lower case error and extra spaces...

Comment: Of course... you could have the user names in an option list.